# Restriction that limits entry to 1 per one unique value in other column

Tags: ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2013 to build a small database for occupancy data entry at a local group of libraries and need to build in some restrictions.

[Database Structure/Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKozK.png)
I want to add in a restriction that limits the entry per one unique location to one per day (to avoid duplicate entry).

It would be nice that when a duplicate is added, a message shows which entry(s) is already in place so this one can be edited when necessary

Hope someone can help as I'm quite new to MS Access :)

Comment: Figured it out myself meanwhile, just didn't know the vocabulary to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, just didn't have the right vocabulary.

You need to select both columns in table design view and mark them both as primary key.

This makes a multi column unique index